# SQL*Loader skips the first character when loading data into a single column

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I'm loading in the following data in the control file and for some reason it is skipping the first character.

Initially the problem was skipping the first character, loading the second character and ignoring the rest! But I fixed this by using `TERMINATED BY '\n'`.

I've added the `UTF8` characterset (because the file is in UTF-8 as stated by Notepad++), but the results are the same with or without it.

I can't find any other information regarding this - the nearest answer was that the `CONTINUEIF` was causing this issue, but I'm not using that. Perhaps SQL*Loader is reading first character of each record for something else?

Here is the table and sequence:

```sql
create table test_table
( id number, raw_data varchar2(100) )
/

create sequence test_seq
/
```

Here is the control file and data. The sequence bit is running fine and populating the `TEST_TABLE.ID` column as expected. The `TEST_DATA.RAW_DATA` column skips the first character of each record (i.e. A, C, E, etc).

```
LOAD DATA
CHARACTERSET UTF8
INFILE * 
TRUNCATE INTO TABLE test_table
(
 id "TEST_SEQ.NEXTVAL",
 raw_data TERMINATED BY '\n'
)
BEGINDATA
A123 B456
C789 D012
E345 F678
J901 K234
L567 M890
```

I'm expecting this to load each line into the `TEST_TABLE.RAW_DATA` column.
Instead it is skipping the first character of each record and happily loading the rest; i.e. the 5 records in `TEST_TABLE.RAW_DATA` are:

```
123 B456
789 D012
345 F678
901 K234
567 M890
```

How can I stop it skipping the first character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your field definition currently says that `id` is a field in your file, and since you haven't specified a data type, it defaults to a single character. Reading that  consumes that first character, which is then discarded as the SQL expression overrides it. The `raw_data` field then starts at the second character.

You can declare that the ID is purely an expression, rather than a field in the data file, [by using the `EXPRESSION` keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-field-list-contents.html#GUID-9D1D0548-E76F-4FFC-B4E9-E69BEF55FE0B):

```
...
(
 id EXPRESSION"TEST_SEQ.NEXTVAL",
 raw_data TERMINATED BY '\n'
)
...
```

It then won't look at (or consume) any data from the file when working out that ID value, and `raw_data` will start from the first character.

You need to terminate the `raw_data` column because you haven't specified a data type for that either, so that would also default to a single character. You could declare that with a size to match your table definition if you prefer:

```
...
(
 id expression "TEST_SEQ.NEXTVAL",
 raw_data CHAR(100)
)
...
```

You could also set a kind-of-dummy `fields terminated by` clause instead. So many options...

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. Makes perfect sense! I've modified my code and ran through some tests - all loaded fine. Also took note of declaring the size explicitly as you suggested and it worked a treat. :)